How to Send Additional User Data for Advanced Matching in Meta After Event in SPA?
In our web app, we trigger a CompleteRegistration event right after the user enters their email. However, other important details required for Meta's Advanced Matching, like phone number, first name, and last name, are only provided by the user at a later stage in the onboarding process.
Is there a way to send this additional data to Meta afterward so that it retroactively links with the initial CompleteRegistration event? If possible, I'd like to ensure that Meta can recognize and match this data to improve tracking accuracy. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

There is an optional event_id parameter, it's a value you can make up. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/server-event It's intended purpose is de-duplication of events send from the client-side using the pixel, and server-side events tracked via the Conversions API. Whether it also works, when you send the same event with different sets of data from the client side multiple times, you'd have to test.
